# TypeScript: Remove an item from Record

Tags: typescript

I have a record

```
type ProductRecord = Record<number, { product: Product; quantity: number }>;
```

This is the list of records;

```
productRecords: ProductRecord[] = ....
```

I would like to remove the `Record` from the list that has key `productId` from the list.

How do I write it the most concise way?

Answer (score 1):

I just find a way to do it:

```
  const index = this.productRecords.indexOf(productRecord, 0);

    if (index > -1) {
        this.productRecords.splice(index, 1);
    }
```